# Alternative way to a == b, without boolean

Tags: java, boolean-logic

I made simple program. I want to stop it when the user enters "5".

Relevant code:

```
do { 
   System.out.println("Enter 5 to quit");    
   a = scanner.nextInt();     
   b = a==5;     
} while (b = true);
```

Of course earlier I named variables (int a, boolean b etc.)

Why doesn't it work when I type:

```
}while (b ==5)
```

PS. Is there a way to refactor code (*while* change to *for*)?

Comment: `while(b = true)` this is always true becaus you assign `true` to `b` (and not comparing it with `==`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while (b = true);`

> you are using = here (assignment) in place of == (relational)
>
> then you used this :
>     `b = a==5;`
>   now as per operator precedence, first a==5 will be executed which may return true or false.
>
> this wont work : `while (b ==5)` as it is not identical to `while (b ==true)` in Java, In C/C++,
>   true is any nonzero value and false is zero. In Java, true and false are nonnumeric values that
>   do not relate to zero or nonzero.
>
> so, you can try :

`while (b == true);`

or

`while (a!=5);`

Answer (score 3):

When doing

```
}while (b = true);
```

you are assigning the value of `true` to `b` so it will always be true

What you want is either

```
}while (b != true);
```

or

```
}while (!b);
```

Answer (score 1):

If entering 5 should get you out of the loop, your condition should be :

```
do {
    ...
} while (!b); // or while (b == false)
```

`while (b == true)` and `while (a == 5)` will keep you in the loop only if 5 was entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
do { 
   System.out.println("Enter 5 to quit");     
} while (scanner.nextInt() != 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

While you need to read the basics of java well, let me answer your question of why

```
} while (b == 5);
```

won't work. It is because you are trying to compare a boolean (you said you had declared b as boolean) with 5 (which is an integer).